# Chroma key (green screen) live for a webcam?

Tags: camera, v4l

Is there a way to apply chroma key live to a stream that's used in video conferencing. Webcam works fine though v4l (Cheese, Ekiga).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/15198/greenscreen-aka-chroma-key-effect-with-a-webcam) but in Linux.

Comment: Found this: https://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio. It hasn't been recently updated, which is less important, and it's not in the repo for Ubuntu. I'd prefer a solution that is.

Comment: The [ffmpeg-specific solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299252/ffmpeg-chroma-key-greenscreen-filter-for-images-video) might be adaptable for this purpose, though you might need to pipe that further on to [v4l2loopback](http://superuser.com/questions/411897/using-desktop-as-fake-webcam-on-linux) to get the composited image showing up as a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

I use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) with [obs-v4l2sink](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink.git), and [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git). I had to build all that (including OBS) from source to get it working in Fedora, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the increased usage of video conferencing in 2020, the already very powerful **WebCamoid** has [recently been upgraded](https://github.com/webcamoid/webcamoid/issues/250) to do exactly what you are asking for. Note though that you need to build it on your own from the github repository, the changes are not yet live in the latest released builds.